# How to display style in php code like this

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a perfect code like this:

```
<h2 class="index-single">Tech Categories</h2><?php
$args2 = array( 'cat' => 11 , 'posts_per_page' => 9 , 'paged' => $paged );

$the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query2->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_template_part( 'thumb' ) . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
} ?>
```

But I do not want to use classes (**ul** and **li**), but
I want to call using code (**row** and **boxer2**

I want to display it later tumbnail parallel.

I've tried to replace the code **ul** > **row**, and **li** > **boxer2**.
But the result is not satisfactory.

Hopefully there is a solution.

Comment: You mean `echo '<li class="row">`?

Comment: you are not currently using any classes beyond the one on the `h2` element. Your are using an html unordered list `ul` with nested list items `li`.

Comment: Can you share more code ^^ ? Where is your css

Comment: "But the result is not satisfactory." Then give us an example of the desired result.

Comment: No ul and li,
I want to use
<Li class = "row"> and <li class = "boxer2">

Comment: perfect how? I can see one obvious coding style error.. but more importantly, I have no idea what you are asking..

Comment: @hassan Row and boxer 2 are bootstrap css

Comment: There's no `boxer2` class in Bootstrap, and you can't replace a `<ul>` with a `<li>` and expect it to work. Put together some plain, working HTML first. Once you've got the HTML working, convert it to dynamic PHP accordingly.

Comment: @ceejayoz Not satisfactory like this:
http://prntscr.com/fdugqi
I want to be parallel like this:
http://prntscr.com/fduh80

Comment: So fix the HTML it's outputting. Again, start with functioning sample HTML, then convert to the dynamic PHP.

Comment: @ceejayoz oke, I will try thoroughly its html

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, just add the desired class in `ul` and `li` elements:

```
if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul class="row">';
    while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query2->the_post();
        echo '<li class="boxer2">' . get_template_part( 'thumb' ) . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```